# ASP.NET MVC ActionLink help

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have the following action link in a view for shows at for example `/Shows/Details/1`

`<%= Html.ActionLink(item.venue, "Details", "Venues", new { name = item.venue }) %>`

This displays the name of the Venue the show is being played at, but I need it to link to the Venue instead of the Shows controller as at the moment the url it is creating is `/Shows/Details?Length=6` when it needs to go to `/Venues/Details?Name=VenueName`

The name of the controller for Venues is VenuesController.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload for the `.ActionLink`.  Try this instead...

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(item.venue, "Details", "Venues", new { name = item.venue }, new {}) %>
```

It is currently selecting [`string, string, object, object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx) overload.  Your "Venues" string is being used for routing data.

Comment: BTW, I'm sure if you check the `a` tag has a `name='{item.value}'` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Add this route to your global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Venue",
    "Venues/{name}",
    new { controller = "Venues", action = "Details", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then call it like this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(item.venue, "Details", "Venues", new { name = item.venue }, new{}) %>
```

it will render:

**/Venue/NameOfTheVenue**

Answer (score -1):

I know it's not the answer to your question but it will help you build better application. I suggest you take a look at T4MVC : http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC it will help you a lot to build your link and get ripped off magic string. I use it for over a year and would never go back. There's also a nice video on Channel 9 : http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/jongalloway/jon-takes-five-with-david-ebbo-on-t4mvc

Hope it helps!